# how to automate scp for multiple server?

Tags: linux, bash

I have IPs of all machines are in one text file,how to do scp from one machine to all machines and automate task?

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: Did you try using a loop (while) to read your file and substitute the ip in your scp command ?

Answer (score 1):

`cat ips.txt | xargs -rtn1 sh -c 'scp /source-file "${1}:/target-file"' --`

You probably need to adjust the command to your actual needs, which you didn't state.

Comment: Don't you mean `${0}`?

Comment: I added the shell options terminator `--` to make it right. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: i want to scp to multiple machines and automate process of giving password

Comment: thanks @Robin479 
I ended by doing like this
for n in $(cat /root/ip.txt);
do
scp  source $n:<dest>
done